# Place Plotly Bar Chart and Box Plot in Front of Line Traces

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have created subplots in `Plotly` that each contain a bar chart (or `boxplot`) and three trace lines. I have created traces at y= 1,2,3 to act as `ablines` like in `ggplot`.

### What the plots look like:

[image: Imgur link to picture of plot]

and

[image: a picture of the subplots].

### Problem:

I want to have it so the bars of the bar chart are **in front** of the trace lines so you should only be able to see the trace lines in between the bars.

### My code currently:

(I have excluded the code that generates the subplots as I don't think it is needed)

```
  generate_plotly_barPlot <- function(dat, showLeg, err) {

    p <- plot_ly(x=dat$xVar, # Initialize graph with line y=2
                 y=2,
                 type="scatter",
                 mode="lines",
                 hoverinfo="none",
                 layer="below",
                 line=list(color="grey",
                           width=2),
                 showlegend=FALSE) %>%
      # Add trace at line y=1
      add_trace(x=dat$xVar,
                y=1,
                type="scatter",
                mode="lines",
                hoverinfo="none",
                line=list(color="grey",
                          width=1.5,
                          dash="dot"),
                inherit=FALSE,
                showlegend=FALSE) %>%
      # Add trace at line y=3
      add_trace(x=dat$xVar,
                y=3,
                type="scatter",
                mode="lines",
                hoverinfo="none",
                line=list(color="grey",
                          width=1.5,
                          dash="dot"),
                inherit=FALSE,
                showlegend=FALSE)%>%
       # Create Bar Chart 
       add_trace(x=dat$xVar, 
                 y=dat$CopyNumber, 
                 type="bar",
                 mode="markers",
                 color=dat$fillColor,
                 orientation="v",
                 inherit=FALSE,
                 marker=list(opacity=1),
                 legendgroup=dat$xVar,
                 showlegend=showLeg,
                 error_y = list(value=dat[[err]],
                                color='#000000',
                                thickness=3,
                                width=6,
                                visible=TRUE))
```

### My approach:

I thought that the order the traces were created would define which layer they would be on in the graph, so since I plotted the bar chart after all of the trace lines, it would sit above them.

I also tried creating shapes to be the `ablines`but it was really difficult to get them in the correct position for subplots. `add_traces` was my best approach. Shapes in plotly have a `layer` parameter to define whether to place the shape above or below ([see the plotly reference](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-shapes-layer)). I was hoping there was something like this that applied to traces, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you started. You did not provide a data set so here is a small made-up example. You can use layout to add a shape (a line in your case) to your graphic. As you can see the bar is above the line. Hope it helps!

```
plot_ly() %>% 
add_bars(x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"), y = c(20, 14, 23)) %>% 
layout(shapes = list(list(type = "lines",x0 = -1, x1 = 3, xref = "x", y0 = 3, y1 = 3, yref = "y", layer = "below")))
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out! I didn't include the data as I thought it would confuse and complicate the example. Could you try generating a shape at line y=3 for each bar chart in a plotly subplot with multiple rows of bar charts? I can post some example data and code to create subplots if you'd like?

Comment: @BunsCode strangely enough, it does not seem to work. See here: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/533. It says the issue is closed but if you run his example it does not work either. It might be a bug.

Comment: I did come across this a while back. I'm thinking it is a bug. I've been unable to get shapes on the correct plot no matter how many approaches I try. I guess I'll have to live with the trace lines sitting above the bar and box plots.

Comment: you can accept the answer if it helped you or give a +1 for the effort :-)

Comment: I gave you a +1, thank you! I may open a github issue on the topic of shapes in subplots and see if that will resolve it.